# move users to a new domain

Tags: active-directory, user-management

I need to move a bunch of user accounts from one domain to another. What is the best way to do this?

I would like to not have to individually change their local profiles as well.

Also, is there anything else that I am not thinking of that I should be doing to make the transition as unnoticeable as possible for the user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few tools available for this. Many from Quest Software, depending on your budget.

For a low-budget alternative, check out [Active Directory Migration Toolkit (ADMT)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ae279d01-7dca-413c-a9d2-b42dfb746059&displaylang=en) from Microsoft.

Comment: Ya but is there a better summed up version of the instructions. Who wants to read the 400 page document. I cant seem to find anything on any sites that give a "here is what you need to do" list.

Comment: I can't support this. An Active Directory migration can cause serious problems in your environment if it's not handled correctly. Either take the time to read the document or hire a consultant who will.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the effort. ADMT is the tool that was needed but the documentation sucks. Never in 15 years have I read the complete documentation for any software and I dont intend to start now. As software development gets supposedly better over the years "they" should be making it easier to use interfaces and easier to manage networks. If not then what's the point? Why would they not want to get better at what they do?

Anywhoo, ADTM worked fine after I figured out the best way to use it. Its not as hard as people are saying and it does not take as much planning as they say if you have an already well setup environment.

Thanks for your help.